# Hierarchical Table and Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario as follows:

```
ManufacturerID        Name
1                     XXX
2                     YYY

DeptID     Name  ManufacturerID
1          abc   1
2          bcd   1
3          efg   2

ProductID   name      deptid
1           dfdfg     1
2           dfdg      2
3           sdfsd     2

PartsID      name      productid
1            sdfs      1
2            sfdfs     2
3            sdd       1
```

I want the above table structure to be made as hierarchical using levels. How do I design the table?

Comment: I don't see where the hierarchy is supposed to be. It looks like you just need joins. The typical hierarchy has a table that references back to itself, usually with ID and ParentID columns.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand what hierarchy you need to make, but if you're using sql server 2008 please take a look at [hierachyId](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manisblog/archive/2007/08/17/sql-server-2008-hierarchyid.aspx) datatype.
And please provide more desdcription about you process. Now it looks straightforward:

Manufacturer has many departments, department has many products, product has many parts.

Comment: When I say hierarchial, i meant something like http://vyaskn.tripod.com/hierarchies_in_sql_server_databases.htm

Comment: Doesn't that depend on how you query and format the resulting data? Your table structure looks fine to me.

Comment: 3 tables means i need to plug in joins.. If we can make the hierarchy in one table we can make joins lesser right?

Comment: I suspect you are trying to use hierarchies to solve the wrong problem.  If you want less joins in your SQL, consider creating a view and querying the view.  Your data looks reasonable normalised.